# What would be time complexity for loop running till 2 to power n

Tags: java, time-complexity

What would be time complexity for loop running till 2 to power n?
Refer to below code snippet.

```
int[] arr={1,2,3,4};
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<Math.pow(2,i);j++){
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, this will not compile. `arr.length()` should be `arr.length`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `n` elements in array you will perform

```
2^0 = 1 computation in first loop
2^1 = 2 computation in second loop
2^2 = 4 computation in third loop
...
2^(n-1) = 2^(n-1) computation in n-th loop
```

Summing all these you get
`2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + ... + 2^(n-1) = 2^n-1` from the formula for sum of geometric series. So your time complexity is `O(2^n)`